# C++ Wrapper for C library as shared library

Tags: c++, c, wrapper

**I SOLVED THIS ISSUE BY MYSELF**

The problem was the linkage of the library.
I copied the libmywrapper.so(i renamed it) file to /usr/lib and linked with -mywrapper
That's it :-)

**Original post:**

I'm writing a wrapper library that allows to call C++ functions out of C-code.
Unfortnuately it doesn't link...

wrapper.h:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"
{
#endif
    extern char* (keygen) ();
#ifdef __cplusplus
 }
#endif
```

wrapper.cpp:

```
#include "wrapper.h"
#include <someincludes>
char* keygen ()
{
    urandom u;
```

Makefile:

```
TARGET      := ./mywrapperlib.so
CXXFLAGS    := -fPIC -shared -g -Wall -std=c++0x -I../someincludes -I.
CXX         := g++
LIB         := -lsomelibs
EXT         := cpp
BUILDDIR    := build

override BUILDDIR := $(strip $(BUILDDIR))
SOURCES  := $(wildcard *.$(EXT))
OBJECTS  := $(patsubst %.$(EXT), $(BUILDDIR)/%.o, $(SOURCES))
DEPS     := $(patsubst %.$(EXT), $(BUILDDIR)/%.dep, $(SOURCES))

.PHONY: all
all: $(TARGET)

$(TARGET): $(OBJECTS) $(DEPS)
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -o $(TARGET) $(OBJECTS) $(LIBS)

ifneq ($(MAKECMDGOALS), clean)
-include $(DEPS)
endif

$(OBJECTS): $(BUILDDIR)/%.o: %.$(EXT) $(BUILDDIR)/%.dep $(BUILDDIR)/.tag
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

$(DEPS): $(BUILDDIR)/%.dep: %.$(EXT) $(BUILDDIR)/.tag
    mkdir -p $(dir $(@))
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -MM $< -MT $@ -MT $(<:.$(EXT)=.o) -o $@

%.tag:
    mkdir -p $(dir $(@))
    touch $@

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    $(RM) -r $(BUILDDIR)
```

A test file that should use the library:
test.c:

```
#include <wrapper.h>
int main()
{
    char* test = keygen();
}
```

When i try to compile it with

```
gcc  -o test.a -g -Iinclude -Llib/mywrapperlib.so test.c
```

I get

```
/tmp/ccB9bEot.o: In function `main':
/some/paths/test.c:7: undefined reference to `keygen'
```

Im very unexperienced with mixing C & C++ code and writing libraries.
Now im stuck and hope that someone can help me with this problem.

EDIT:

I checked the lib with nm:

```
nm lib/cryptdbwrapperlib.so | grep keygen
0000000000006935 T keygen
```

So, i guess that the problem is the linkage...

Comment: did the question title make sense when you wrote it? ;)

Comment: i fixed the spelling mistake and the title ;-)

Comment: If you fixed the problem, post an answer. Please don't write solutions in questions.

Comment: Um, is the title backward?  The title as it stands now says you are calling a C library from C++.  I think you really want to say you are calling a C++ shared library from C.

Answer (score 1):

It's to do with the order of your flags to `gcc`.

Do this:

```
gcc  -o test.a -g -Iinclude test.c -Llib/mywrapperlib.so
#                           ^^^^^^ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
#                           first    second
```

GCC reads libraries and objects left-to-right and (basically) ignores any that aren't needed "yet". With my proposed change, `test.c` goes first so GCC knows that it's going to be looking for a symbol `keygen`; then, when it finally sees `-Llib/mywrapperlib.so` it scans it for `keygen`, finds it, and knows that this library is required.

Comment: Note the real problem, that line is not linking to the shared object, it's just specifying an (invalid) path to search for libraries (-L , a -l argument is needed too and likely the shared library should be named libmywrapper.so so you can do -Llib -lmywrapper)

Answer (score 0):

Change the function's signature in `wrapper.cpp` to

```
extern "C" char* keygen ()
```

Otherwise it will be compiled with a C++ style name, and hence be a different function than the one declared in the header.

Comment: No, the linkage only needs to be specified in the initial declaration.

Answer (score 0):

**I SOLVED THIS ISSUE BY MYSELF**

The problem was the linkage of the library. I copied the libmywrapper.so(i renamed it) file to /usr/lib and linked with -mywrapper That's it :-)